# Why does Rider suggests me to use deconstruction?

Tags: c#, rider

I'm writing this class:

```
private class SameCellsComparer : EqualityComparer<Links> 
{
    public override bool Equals(Links t1, Links t2)
    {
        return t1 == null || t1.Equals(t2);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode(Links t)
    {
        // we suppose there will always be less than 100 000 000 items:
        return t.Item1.id + t.Item2.id * 100000000;
    }
}
```

But Rider suggests me to use deconstruction on `GetHashCode(Links t)`, and if I apply the suggestion, I get this:

```
private class SameCellsComparer : EqualityComparer<Links> 
{
    public override bool Equals(Links t1, Links t2)
    {
        return t1 == null || t1.Equals(t2);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode(Links t)
    {
        // we suppose there will always be less than 100 000 000 items:
        (Cell item1, Cell item2) = t;
        return item1.id + item2.id * 100000000;
    }
}
```

Please don't talk about doing bad `GetHashCode()` principle, I'm only asking for the conversion to `(Cell item1, Cell item2) = t`: is it safer, faster, cleaner? I don't get it.

Comment: If you look on the [list of all inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference__Code_Inspections_CSHARP.html#LanguageUsage) The default severity level of this is "Hint" - the lowest level, which is [described as](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Analysis__Code_Inspections.html#hints) "Code issues with this severity bring your attention to a particular code detail and/or recommends a way of improvement".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just a syntax sugar.
With deconstruction you can control the name of the tuple items.

Check this [gist](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABATARgFgAobAZgAI8KBhCgbxIuasuwBYKBZACgEoGTFsJ7Z8ABgoAzGUgDKMBAEsAdgHNpM3AIC8tAHQARAPb8A3EOHNLVgG4QEFADYU9NI6b4XiwgL43Lcip8ADYKHgVldQoIJApI1Q1gARN+Rh8rKgB2cIAiCALcuNzgWzLbXK9Lf2JfIA==) I created.

For this `C#` code:

```
using System;
public class C {
    public void M() {
        (string fff,String fff2) = C.Do();
        
        var l = C.Do();
    }
    
   public static (String a, String b) Do(){
       return ("aaa", "bvvvv");
   }
}
```

Compiler see it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[module: UnverifiableCode]
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        ValueTuple<string, string> valueTuple = Do();
        string item = valueTuple.Item1;
        string item2 = valueTuple.Item2;
        ValueTuple<string, string> valueTuple2 = Do();
    }

    [return: TupleElementNames(new string[] {
        "a",
        "b"
    })]
    public static ValueTuple<string, string> Do()
    {
        return new ValueTuple<string, string>("aaa", "bvvvv");
    }
}
```

Notice that this lines:

```
  ValueTuple<string, string> valueTuple = Do();
        string item = valueTuple.Item1;
        string item2 = valueTuple.Item2;
        ValueTuple<string, string> valueTuple2 = Do();
```

Are approximately the same code.

[image: screenshot of the gist]